# Ext HDD Seagate Backup Plus 4TB lists incorrect size

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

The drive is new. It is a 4TB backup disk that shows 1TB available in Windows 7, 10, Debian, Ubuntu, Mint and OSX. No amount of pushing or cajoling seems to change that.

I am not a noob. I have run GParted and dropped the partition, rewritten the partition table, used various OS from Windows to several distros of Linux and Active@Bootdisk including numerous Partition Managers and lastly Killdisk to write zeros on it.

It wipes, writes, formats, initiates and mounts just fine. But only with 1TB.

Comment: Could you run `wmic diskdrive get Model` in a command prompt and post the model number?

Comment: What is the output of `hdparm -N /dev/sdX` in Linux?

Comment: You may need to format the disk using GPT if it's MBR formatted. If you're running Windows 10 Creator's Update (i.e. Build 15063. You can verify by running `wmic os get version` and check if you're on that build) there's a [built-in MBR2GPT utility](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/mbr2gpt-tool-windows-10) to do this. Run `powershell -Command "Get-Disk | ft -Auto"`, find your HDD in the list (check "Friendly Name" column to identify your disk) and check if the "Partiton Style" column says "MBR" or "GPT".

Comment: MBR drives can't get over 2TB

Comment: Did you put a 4TB internal disk in your own enclosure? If so, that's likely the problem -- many USB enclosures have 32-bit address limits, which means they can handle a maximum disk size of 2TiB. Beyond that and they typically "wrap around," like a car's odometer. The solution is to use the disk in a way that does not impose a 32-bit sector address limit. Connecting it internally, via an external eSATA enclosure, or via a newer external USB enclosure that "translates" eight groups of 512-byte sectors into 4096-byte sectors should all work.